# Multiple call of method of objects in another class

Tags: python, oop

Method `sound()` in class `BellTower` should call method `sound()` of classes `BigBell` and `LittleBell`, but there are unknown number of args passed to the object. How can I call `sound()` for all of them? I almost tried to parse list, but 'str' object is not callable.(`elem.sound() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`)

```
class LittleBell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = 'ding'

    def sound(self):
        print(self.sound)

class BigBell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.checker = True
        self.sound = 'ding'
        self.bigsound = 'dong'

    def sound(self):
        if (self.checker):
            print(self.sound)
            self.checker = False
        elif not(self.checker):
            print(self.sound)
            self.checker = True

class BellTower:
    def __init__(self, *bells):
        self.bells = list(bells)

    def sound(self):
        for elem in self.bells:
            elem.sound()
        print('...')
```

it should work like this:

```
bell_tower = BellTower(BigBell(), LittleBell())
bell_tower.sound()
=>
ding
ding
...
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  The code you posted seems to do exactly what you want (except that `BigBell` is always using `self.sound`, never `self.bigsound`).

Comment: Oh, you're using the name `sound` for both an attribute and a method - rename one of those.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you could try to create a parent class `generalBell` wich specifies the `sound` method, and has the `noise` attribute. Both small and big bells implement this class, call it upon creation, and you can then even specify the type of all of the bells, and even use an if statement to detect non-bells being passed as bells.